# Nodejs Prisma include does not respect grandparent id

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I am using prisma orm in nodejs and have the following schema (example)

```
model User
{
    id  Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    answers Answer[]

}

model Product
{
    id  Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    questions  Question[]
}

model Question
{
    id  Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    products    Product[]
    answers     Answer[]
}

model Answer
{
    id  Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    userId Int
    user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

    productId Int
    product Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])

    questionId Int
    question Question @relation(fields: [questionId], references: [id])
}
```

Is it possible to get a list of products with questions and with latest answer for each question?

The problem I have is, that nested includes don't respect grandparent id.

For example, in this code:

```
let products = await prisma.product.findMany({
    include: {
        questions: {
            include: {
                answers: true
            }
        }
    }
})
```

returned answers for each question don't also belong to the product I want them to belong to.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have two questions. Firstly, If a single ```Question``` can be related with multiple ```Product``` records, then why is an answer for a certain ```Question``` only related to one ```Product```. Shouldn't it be associated with all the ```Products``` that the ```Question``` itself is associated with? I don't know anything about your business logic/domain and I could be wrong, so clarification would help.  Secondly, the ```Answer[]``` relation is missing from the ```User``` and ```Product``` model of your schem,a. Is this accidental?

Comment: Its just evaluation for now, but here is the sample data.
For example, there is "phone" and "phone case" products, and the questions are "how are you satisfied with your product" and "how are you satisfied with the shipping/packing"

User then gives answer for each question-product pair, so "How are you satisfied with your product" - for product "phone" 
and 
How are you satisfied with your product" - for product "phone case"

and similarly for the second question. 

regarding Answer[] relation, its accidental yes, I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it's not possible to make the query you're looking for (A second layer of nested include that also respects the grandparent ID).

A possible workaround is to include the answers *alongside* the questions in the `product` query instead of nesting it inside `questions`. Then you can merge the questions and answers in the application layer (either in the backend or frontend, whichever is most appropriate).

The code would look something like this

```js
    let products = await prisma.product.findMany({
        include: {
            questions: true,
            answers: true,  // Assuming the relation field is called answers. You confirmed you accidentally forgot to mention the field in your schema. 
        },
    });

// In Javascript/Typescript: For every product, iterate across every answer and add to the questions array.
```

This workaround should work reasonably well provided the number of products/answers isn't incredibly large.